# Сжатие приложение

Tags: android

Создал простую программу, но оно весит около 4 МБ  Я хочу сжать его до 2 МБ. Прописал в build.gradle(app) код:

`minifyEnabled true`

Но вес уменьшается на 200-300 КБ. Можно как то это реализовать?

Comment: А библиотек у вас там внешних сколько? Ресурсов?

Comment: Какие библиотеки?

Comment: Любые библиотеки.

Comment: Внутри программы нет библиотек

Comment: Эх, простите. В секции dependencies `{compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0' compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`

Comment: С помощью build->analize apk можно посмотреть что сколько весит в собранном приложении. И станет чуточку понятнее что именно нужно ужать или выбросить

Comment: Спасибо попробую.